# Fastest way to write to SQL server database from java program

Tags: java

Here is the problem.
I have to persist information hits my application at the rate of 30files/second.
So some information needs to be persisted to the disk to accomaodate for sudden outage scenarios etc.
The disk contents need to be persisted to a sql server database.
i am using jtds driver to pass all the information.
However i am using a single thread that does the writing to the database part.
Is there a framework that can help me persist this information at the rate required?

Comment: I do not fully understand that. Do you first write to disk and then to database? How does a 'file' look like, binary data, size, etc.?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck? Is processing the files expensive? Or is persisting the data to the DB expensive? Some more information about your problem would help.

Comment: Yeah so here is the current implementation that i am working on , the independent serialized objects are received and written into separate files on the disk. This is currently being done by a thread say t1. Another thread t2 consumes these files which are maintained in the form of a queue and goes on writing them to the database. The queue that i am talking about is a singleton and so the queue is consumed one file/object at a time and written to the database. i need to find a way to speed up the "reading from files deserialize and write to the database" part by much.